# Reference FrameworkAssembly in netcoreapp1.0

Tags: c#, .net-core

What is the prefered way to reference full framework assemblies like `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` on a netcoreapp that runs windows only?

The dnx supported this way:

```
 "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Messaging": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Runtime.Serialization": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
```

and with netcore it changed to:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
```

Comment: What kind of application do you work on? For class libraries, you simply use the proper monikers https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/blob/netcore5/SharpSnmpLib/project.json

Comment: Thanks @LexLi, it would perfectly for a class library. However, I couldn't reference it from a WebApplication: "The following projects are not supported as references : 
  - ClassLibrary2 has target frameworks that are incompatible with targets in current project WebApplication12. 
WebApplication12:
 .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
ClassLibrary2:
 .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `frameworkAssemblies` still works for me.

If you want to use the assembly directly from your ASP.NET Core application, then the project.json would look like this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
},

"frameworks": {
  "net461": {
    "frameworkAssemblies": {
      "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement": "4.0.0.0"
    }
  }
},
```

If you want to do it indirectly through a class library, then the project.json in the class library would look like this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027"
},

"frameworks": {
  "net461": {
    "frameworkAssemblies": {
      "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement": "4.0.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

And in the application (assuming the class library is called `ClassLibrary`):

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "ClassLibrary": "1.0.0-*"
},

"frameworks": {
  "net461": {}
},
```